# Adding a node just after one node (jstree)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm creating a tree using jstree javascript library https://www.jstree.com/ .I need to create a new node just after current node as a sibling.

- Elem 1
- Elem 2
- Elem 3

My point is when i click on Elem 2 a new node say Elem 2.5 is added in between Elem 2 and Elem 3

so result:--

- Elem 1
- Elem 2
- Elem 2.5
- Elem 3

My current code:
`$(".appendTree").jstree('create_node', CurrentNode, html, 'last');`

by this new ,nodes are always added at the end.is there any api or workaround to handle this??

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes,I made some changes in jstree.create method.There was an "after" method ,i altered the method according to following procedure ,first i find out the current node's  index,then i created new node at index+1 position  solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to figure out the current index for the selected node in the current folder, then pass the index to `create_node` method instead of your `last`. See code below.  Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/5qb28g8L/).

```
$('.appendTree')
        .jstree({   
        core : {
            check_callback : true,
            data : coredata
        }
    })
    .on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var $parent = $('#'+data.node.id).parent();
                var index = $parent.children().index( $('#'+data.node.id) ) +1;

        if(data.node.parent === '#') {
            $parent = '#';
        }

        $(".appendTree").jstree('create_node', $parent, 'new node', index);
    });
```